# Chaining Multiple Promise.alls with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using the Wordpress API with Fetch to put together a global variable with all the data I need to populate a page on load. However, this series of fetches completes after the page loads, thus defeating the purpose. I'm trying to string together nested Promise.alls to force the completion of this function before displaying the page data, but so far have had no luck getting it to work. The function itself works, just not the promises. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getProjects() {
  console.log('projects')
  var returnProject = function(project) {
    if(project.better_featured_image) {
      return {
        project_name: project.title.rendered,
        project_desc: project.content.rendered,
        project_img: project.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url
      }
    } else {
      return {
        project_name: project.title.rendered,
        project_desc: project.content.rendered
      }
    }
  }

  fetch('http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/categories')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(categories => {
    Promise.all(categories.map(category => {
      return Promise.all(data.map(service => {
        if(service.service_name == category.name) {
          fetch(`http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/projects?categories=${category.id}`)
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then(projects => {
            service.projects = projects.map(project => returnProject(project));
          })
        }
      }))
    }))
  })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the function itself works, just not the promises"?  The whole point of promises is to allow the rest of the code to execute while waiting on a response from the promise.

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but you could send the user to a page that displays what you want to display before the promises return and then redirect the user once the promises are fulfilled.

Comment: where do you call the getProjects method?

Comment: You are not returning the outer `fetch` promise or the innermost `fetch` promises. The inner ones in particular need to be returned, otherwise the `Promise.all(data.map(service => ...` is relatively pointless since you just end with an array of `undefined`, which will resolve the `Promise.all` immediately.

Comment: The other option that is better than my redirect suggestion is to wrap the page in a div that is hidden, once the data loads you can show that div.

Comment: "*completion of this function before displaying the page data*" - where are you displaying the page data?

Comment: @CRice isn't the outmost promise returned with the middle Promise.all?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `return Promise.all(data.map(service => ...` only returns from the function it's contained in, in this case the `category => {` map function. It does not return from the `getProjects` function. Right now, `getProjects` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Below you will find a working snippet that uses `Promise.all()` in two levels

```js
// Nesting of promises in multiple levels:
// after finding all users in the first fetch
// we get all the posts for each of the users in the first Promise.all()
// and finally we get the comments for each of the posts (these have been flattened before...)
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
fetch(url + 'users').then(r => r.json()).then(users => {
  Promise.all(users.map(u => fetch(url + 'users/' + u.id + '/posts').then(r => r.json())))
    .then(uposts =>
      Promise.all(uposts.flat().map(p => fetch(url + "posts/" + p.id + "/comments").then(r => r.json())))
      .then(console.log)
    )
})
```